# Directional derivatives, continuity at $0$ and differentiability of $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy^6}{x^4+y^8},(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\0,(x,y)=0\\\end{cases}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

I have solved the following problem and I would appreciate some feedback on my solution, thanks:

Let $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy^6}{x^4+y^8},(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\0,(x,y)=0\\\end{cases}$.

(a) Find all the directional derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$.

(b) Is f continuous at $(0,0)$?

(c) Is f differentiable at $(0,0)$?

My solution:

(a) $$D_{\mathbf{v}}f=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(\mathbf{0}+t\mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{0})}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{tv_1t^6v_2^2}{t^4v_1^4+t^8v_2^8}\frac{1}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0} t^2\frac{v_1v_2^6}{v_1^4+t^4v_2^8}=0,$$ where $\mathbf{v}=(v_1,v_2)\neq (0,0).$

(b) $f(x,mx)=x^3\frac{m^6}{1+m^8x^4}\xrightarrow{(x,y)\to (0,0)}0$ but $f(x,\sqrt{x})=\frac{1}{2}$ so $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist and $f$ is thus not continuous at $(0,0).$

(c) $f$ cannot be differentiable at $(0,0)$ since it is not continuous at $(0,0).$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: There is a problem in your first limit of b). Notice how the answer to the first limit still depends on $x$ looks like you forget the limit symbols.

Comment: @Olivier The body of the post was edited after I posted my comment.